# x64 or x32 best for virtualbox to install windows 8 or 7

Tags: 64-bit

I have a Lenovo G580 Laptop, I work in IT Support and we need Windows for work, so I would like to install Ubuntu and use Windows 8 in a Virtual Box.

Should I use x86 or x64 for Better Performance?

Comment: you have x64 cpu so you should install x64 windows

Comment: Like others said, x64bit. I have Ubuntu running with Windows and Mac virtualised.

Answer (score 3):

If you have x64 CPU and you run a x32 application (or OS) you simply waste some of CPU performance because some of CPU registers are simply useless. It won't make it faster.
So simply use x64 if you can.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the evaluation version of 8 that you're trying to install in VB then you'll find that the 64 bit won't work regardless of whither the architecture of your machine suits 64 bit. I ended up having to install a 32 bit version in spite of my machine managing fine with any other 64 bit O/S natively.

Microsoft CS confirmed this for me once I rang them.

Answer (score 1):

If your Ubuntu is 64Bit then install the 64bit version of Windows.

The reasons are :

- You avoid a very small performance issue : if you install 32bit of windows on a 64bit ubuntu virtualbox then you ask Virtualbox to do some extra work.
- If you need to give 4Gb or more ram to your Windows VM then only the 64bit version of windows will be able to use them

Question : Why windows 8 and not 7 ? in a VM and for IT use there is not much reasons to go to Windows 8 unless that you want to consume a lot more resources (witch is the important part when you do a VM).

Tip : Downgrade the best you can the graphical interface of your windows vm (even if it's ugly). It'll really boost your vm performance.